# Cordova app using angular & ADAL

Tags: angularjs, cordova, azure-active-directory, visual-studio-cordova, adal

I'm building my first mobile app using Cordova. The back-end services live on Azure so I'm trying to get authentication working by using the ADAL plugin for Cordova.

First of all I found out that the library does not do intercepts as the ADAL library for Angular does. I'm using Angular within my Cordova app, paired with material design directives for the look-and-feel. Would have been nice to have interception, but as I understood it's just not there at the moment (should find out how hard it is to implement).

So instead I now wrote a service which will take care of sending REST api requests to Azure, including the correct authentication token. It's based on the sample found [here](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-cordova).

This is what I came up with:

```
var request = function(url)
{
    createContext()
        .then(function () {
            getAuthToken().then(
                function(token) {
                    sendRequest(token, url);
            })
        },
        function (err) {
            $log.error("Failed to create a context.");
        });
};
```

First it will create the authentication context:

```
function createContext () {
    return $q(function (resolve, reject) {
        var authenticationContext = Microsoft.ADAL.AuthenticationContext;

        authenticationContext.createAsync(authority)
            .then(function (context) {
                authContext = context;
                $log.log("Created authentication context for authority URL: " + context.authority);
                resolve();
            }, function (err) {
                $log.error("Failed to create authentication context: " + pre(err))
                reject();
            });
    });
};
```

The using the context it should get the authentication token:

```
function getAuthToken()
{
    if (authContext == null) {
        $log.error('Authentication context isn\'t created yet. Create context first');
        return;
    }

    return $q(function (resolve, reject) {
        authContext.acquireTokenAsync(resourceUrl, appId, redirectUrl)
            .then(function (authResult) {
                resolve(authResult.accessToken);
            }, function (err) {
                $log.error("Failed to acquire token: " + pre(err));
                reject();
            });
    });
}
```

And afterwards it should send the request but I'll leave that part out since it never gets there anyway. I feel the need to re-emphasize that I'm a complete n00b at this stuff, so please be easy on me and especially on the code. There's probably a lot of room for improvement, I get that.

When I actually run this, it pops up a window where I need to login using my Microsoft account, cool. I even got two factor authentication first time I tried this, very nice! So I log in and I get returned to the code. But now the **authresult** variable has a status of "Failed" and there's no access token in the result. Unfortunately there's also no indication of what went wrong. So first part of the question is; what could have gone wrong here?

Now we get to the second part of the question; how do you properly debug these kinds of things? On my desktop I'd run Fiddler to check out the communication, but I don't know how to do that for Android. I'm debugging on my device btw, cause for some reason all of the emulators available to me are extremely slow (VS and Google) even though my hardware specs should support them just fine.

Thanks for any pointers!

**Update 03-02-2016**

Fiddling around with the code a bit, I decided to pack things in a login function which gives a somewhat shorter sample:

```
var createContext = function () {
    if (authContext == null) {
        authContext = new Microsoft.ADAL.AuthenticationContext(authority);
    }
};

var getAuthToken = function () {
    if (authContext == null) {
        $log.error('Authentication context isn\'t created yet. Create context first');
        return;
    }

    return $q(function (resolve, reject) {
        authContext.acquireTokenAsync(endpointUrl, appId, redirectUrl)
            .then(function (authResult) {
                resolve(authResult.accessToken);
            }, function (err) {
                $log.error("Failed to acquire token: " + pre(err));
                reject();
            });
    });
}

var login = function () {
    createContext();
    getAuthToken();
}
```

This code runs on the following input vars:

```
var authority = 'https://login.windows.net/[tenantid]';
var resourceUrl = 'https://graph.windows.net/';
var appId = '1ef41b17-0943-4359-bc12-014f4fd2d841';
var redirectUrl = 'http://MyApp';
```

I now used chrome://inspect to see what is going over the wire. And to my big surprise, I see a valid SAML token returned from Azure. It has got my name in it and everything, which I'd recon they wouldn't send after a failed authentication. So it seems that even though the response is ok, the ADAL library doesn't give me a proper response (Status = Failed). Again no clue on how to proceed :S

Comment: Have your configured your app in Azure? https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-native-multitarget#step-4--register-the-sample-with-your-azure-active-directory-tenant . To debug the network calls in android, you can attach to your device (or to your emulator) with chrome using chrome://inspect

Comment: Yeah Azure is setup ok, I'm pretty sure of that. Mobile is new to me, Azure isn't :) thanks for the chrome tip, that definitely sounds very useful and I'll try that!

Comment: Is it Android only? Can you try another platform -  Windows for example as it is easy to debug/profile as native bridge is javascript also.

Comment: Hmm, good suggestion @SergeiGrebnov, I tried using Windows instead but that fails as well. Little bit more error output though: error = "authentication_failed" errorDescription = "Specified method is not supported."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just solved it. And like one would expect, the remedy is as simple as they get. Configuring the application in Azure AD, I chose the "web application" type application, since this is a web application with Angular and all. Now I guess since Cordova translates things to native code, that's not the correct option to chose. As soon as I created a new application as "native application" instead and used the client ID of that one, everything started working.... Sincerely hope this will help someone else in the future...!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/122036/jasper I am stuck at same issue, I will let you know how I got on after trying your solution...

Comment: What library are you using ? do you have the link for it ?

Comment: @Ron ADAL.js, but as this was 2 years ago the code might not work any more with the current version. I haven't updated this code.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar issue where I was trying to access a web api from a Cordova app. I was using the App ID Uri for the web api I wanted to access as the resouceURL when calling acquireTokenAsync. When I changed this to the client Id of the Web Api instead it worked.

Comment: I'm calling acquireTokenAsync with the following parameters: resourceUrl (https://graph.windows.net/), appId (the GUID of my app in Azure AD and redirectUrl; the URL configured in Azure AD as valid return URL. This URL doesn't actually exist, but as far as I understood that doesn't matter. You used the appId GUID as resourceURL? Doens't make sense but I can try I guess.

Comment: Didn't make sense to me but it worked :). If you can remote debug the browser on the device from a PC/Laptop (i.e using Safari/Chrome) then you should be able to get the URL that the plugin is using to authenticate. Copy the URL, open an incognito window, and try and login using the same credentials, check the URL it redirects to as this may contain a more helpful error message.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. Btw did you switch the arguments around, or use the ID twice?

Comment: First argument was client Id for my web api service, second was the client id for my cordova app.

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean. I have a client id (GUID) for the application I registered in Azure AD. That's the one I'm using as client ID for the moment. Which ID do you have for web api? Where is that one found? Or is it the URL of the service?

Comment: When you say you are connecting to a backend service on Azure, is this a REST service you have developed or are you simply sending requests to the Graph API?

Comment: At the moment, I'm simply querying the Graph API. But indeed it's the plan to call a REST service I developed myself, just thought it would be better to get started with a foolproof example :S

Comment: BTW I also tried your idea of using the client ID of the webapi service. That first triggered an error stating that I didn't set the delegate permissions (which I didn't). Having that solved, it returned to the original error failing to login completely. I'm starting to think it might have something to do with the API versioning and maybe things have changed in the meantime.

Comment: This seems like a permissions/configuration issue in Azure - If you put the token in http://jwt.io/ what header properties are present?

Comment: Hmmm not quite sure on how to get that? What I get in response is a SAML (XML) based token. That one contains the following claims: Managed, LastName, Child, TOUAccepted, CID, EmailAddress, FirstName, PUID. So perhaps the config issue here is that it should be returning json instead? Will check the manifest whether that's configurable.

Comment: It's not configurable, which is what I'd expect since you probably want the caller to specify which format they need returned. If the HTML/XML response is what is expected; then what exactly should I parse in jwt.io?